# Is there a way to change the directory to which the Android Asset Studio saves resources?

Tags: android, android-resources, android-asset-studio

Every time I use the Android Asset Studio to add a new vector drawable to my localized app, the drawable gets saved to the res-localizable/drawable folder and I need to go in there and manually change it to res/drawable.
It's a pain to always have to remember to change it. Is there a way I could change the default directory?

I tried adding source sets to my build.gradle with no luck

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDir(file("src/main/res"))
        resources.srcDir(file("src/main/res"))
        assets.srcDir(file("src/main/res"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after updating to Electric Eel and deleting the jre folder, now I can see the option of saving to both my res and res-localizable folder in the Asset Studio Source Set input.